# Scrapy hidden memory leak

Tags: python, memory, scrapy, scrapinghub

**Background** - TLDR: I have a memory leak in my project

Spent a few days looking through the memory leak docs with scrapy and can't find the problem.
I'm developing a medium size scrapy project, ~40k requests per day.

I am hosting this using scrapinghub's scheduled runs.

On [scrapinghub](https://app.scrapinghub.com), for $9 per month, you are essentially given 1 VM, with 1GB of RAM, to run your crawlers.

I've developed a crawler locally and uploaded to scrapinghub, the only problem is that towards the end of the run, I exceed the memory.

Localling setting `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=16` works fine, but leads to exceeding the memory on scrapinghub at the 50% point. When I set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=4`, I exceed the memory at the 95% point, so reducing to 2 should fix the problem, but then my crawler becomes too slow.

The alternative solution, is paying for 2 VM's, to increase the RAM, but I have a feeling that the way I've set up my crawler is causing memory leaks.

For this example, the project will scrape an online retailer.
When run locally, my `memusage/max` is 2.7gb with `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=16`.

**I will now run through my scrapy structure**

1. Get the total number of pages to scrape
2. Loop through all these pages using: [www.example.com/page={page_num}](http://www.example.com/page=%7Bpage_num%7D)
3. On each page, gather information on 48 products
4. For each of these products, go to their page and get some information
5. Using that info, call an API directly, for each product
6. Save these using an item pipeline (locally I write to csv, but not on scrapinghub)

- **Pipeline**

```
    class Pipeline(object):
        def process_item(self, item, spider):
            item['stock_jsons'] = json.loads(item['stock_jsons'])['subProducts']
            return item
```

- **Items**

```
    class mainItem(scrapy.Item):
        date = scrapy.Field()
        url = scrapy.Field()
        active_col_num = scrapy.Field()
        all_col_nums = scrapy.Field()
        old_price = scrapy.Field()
        current_price = scrapy.Field()
        image_urls_full = scrapy.Field()
        stock_jsons = scrapy.Field()
    
    class URLItem(scrapy.Item):
        urls = scrapy.Field()
```

- Main spider

```
    class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'product'
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            page = requests.get('www.example.com', headers=headers)
            self.num_pages = # gets the number of pages to search
    
        def start_requests(self):
            for page in tqdm(range(1, self.num_pages+1)):
                url = 'www.example.com/page={page}'
                yield scrapy.Request(url = url, headers=headers, callback = self.prod_url)

        def prod_url(self, response):
            urls_item = URLItem()
            extracted_urls = response.xpath(####).extract() # Gets URLs to follow
            urls_item['urls'] = [# Get a list of urls]
            for url in urls_item['urls']:
                    yield scrapy.Request(url = url, headers=headers, callback = self.parse)

        def parse(self, response) # Parse the main product page
            item = mainItem()
            item['date'] = DATETIME_VAR
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['active_col_num'] = XXX
            item['all_col_nums'] = XXX
            item['old_price'] = XXX
            item['current_price'] = XXX
            item['image_urls_full'] = XXX

            try:
                new_url = 'www.exampleAPI.com/' + item['active_col_num']
            except TypeError:
                new_url = 'www.exampleAPI.com/{dummy_number}'
        
            yield scrapy.Request(new_url, callback=self.parse_attr, meta={'item': item})


        def parse_attr(self, response):
        ## This calls an API Step 5
            item = response.meta['item']
            item['stock_jsons'] = response.text
            yield item
```

What I've tried so far?

- psutils, haven't helped too much.
- `trackref.print_live_refs()` returns the following at the end:

```
HtmlResponse                       31   oldest: 3s ago
mainItem                            18   oldest: 5s ago
ProductSpider                       1   oldest: 3321s ago
Request                            43   oldest: 105s ago
Selector                           16   oldest: 3s ago
```

- printing the top 10 global variables, over time
- printing the top 10 item types, over time

**QUESTIONS**

- How can I find the memory leak?
- Can anyone see where I may be leaking memory?
- Is there a fundamental problem with my scrapy structure?

*Please let me know if there is any more information required*

**Additional Information Requested**

- Note, the following output is from my local machine, where I have plenty of RAM, so the website I am scraping becomes the bottleneck. When using scrapinghub, due to the 1GB limit, the suspected memory leak becomes the problem.

Please let me know if the output from scrapinghub is required, I think it should be the same, but the message for finish reason, is memory exceeded.

1.Log lines from start(from INFO: Scrapy xxx started to spider opened).

```
2020-09-17 11:54:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.3.0 started (bot: PLT)
2020-09-17 11:54:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) - [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 3.1, Platform Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2020-09-17 11:54:11 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'PLT',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 14,
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 14,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.05,
 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'PLT.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['PLT.spiders']}
2020-09-17 11:54:11 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: # blocked
2020-09-17 11:54:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-09-17 11:54:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-09-17 11:54:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
=======
17_Sep_2020_11_54_12
=======
2020-09-17 11:54:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['PLT.pipelines.PltPipeline']
2020-09-17 11:54:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
```

2.Ending log lines (INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats to end).

```
2020-09-17 11:16:43 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 15842233,
 'downloader/request_count': 42031,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 42031,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1108804016,
 'downloader/response_count': 42031,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 41999,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 9,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/504': 22,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 110,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 3325.171148,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 17, 10, 16, 43, 258108),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 10,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/403': 9,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/404': 1,
 'item_scraped_count': 20769,
 'log_count/INFO': 75,
 'memusage/max': 2707484672,
 'memusage/startup': 100196352,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 42009,
 'retry/count': 22,
 'retry/reason_count/504 Gateway Time-out': 22,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 42031,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 42031,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 42031,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 42031,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 17, 9, 21, 18, 86960)}
2020-09-17 11:16:43 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

3. what value used for self.num_pages variable?

The site I am scraping has around 20k products, and shows 48 per page. So it goes to the site, see's 20103 products, then divides by 48 (then math.ceil) to get the number of pages.

4. Adding the output from scraping hub after updating the middleware

```
downloader/request_bytes    2945159
downloader/request_count    16518
downloader/request_method_count/GET 16518
downloader/response_bytes   3366280619
downloader/response_count   16516
downloader/response_status_count/200    16513
downloader/response_status_count/404    3
dupefilter/filtered 7
elapsed_time_seconds    4805.867308
finish_reason   memusage_exceeded
finish_time 1600567332341
httperror/response_ignored_count    3
httperror/response_ignored_status_count/404 3
item_scraped_count  8156
log_count/ERROR 1
log_count/INFO  94
memusage/limit_reached  1
memusage/max    1074937856
memusage/startup    109555712
request_depth_max   2
response_received_count 16516
retry/count 2
retry/reason_count/504 Gateway Time-out 2
scheduler/dequeued  16518
scheduler/dequeued/disk 16518
scheduler/enqueued  17280
scheduler/enqueued/disk 17280
start_time  1600562526474
```

Comment: Additional Info required: 1.Log lines from start(from `INFO: Scrapy xxx started` to `spider opened`). 2.Ending log lines (`INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats` to end).
3. what value used for `self.num_pages` variable?

Comment: Added, hope this helps, thanks for the detailed request - made adding this very easy @Georgiy

Comment: What is your meaning of "my crawler becomes too slow"?
In general case it is not normal to send requests to website more frequently than 1 req per second. Your spider sent 42k requests in 54 minutes (~13 requests per second)!!.

Comment: Hi @Georgiy, Sorry, I will add more context to the answer, this output is from running it on my local machine, with 16 concurrent crawlers at 0.05 requests rate. I have to reduce this to 4, when using scraping hub, from what I suspect is a memory leak, not the website throttling.

Comment: TLDR solution: Scrapy cloud units on Scraping Hub, and reduce the request rate. If that isn't working, look at the below answer to go deeper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.Scheruler queue/Active requests** 
with `self.numpages = 418`.

this code lines will create 418 request objects (including -to ask OS to delegate memory to hold 418 objects) and put them into scheduler queue :

```
for page in tqdm(range(1, self.num_pages+1)):
                url = 'www.example.com/page={page}'
                yield scrapy.Request(url = url, headers=headers, callback = self.prod_url)
```

each "page" request generate 48 new requests.
each "product page" request generate 1 "api_call" request
each "api_call" request returns item object.
As all requests have equal priority - on the worst case application will require memory to hold ~20000 request/response objects in RAM at once.

In order to exclude this cases `priority` parameter can be added to `scrapy.Request`.
And probably You will need to change spider configuration to something like this:

```
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url = 'www.example.com/page=1', headers=headers, callback = self.prod_url)

    def prod_url(self, response):
        #get number of page
        next_page_number = int(response.url.split("/page=")[-1] + 1
        #...
        for url in urls_item['urls']:
                yield scrapy.Request(url = url, headers=headers, callback = self.parse, priority = 1)

        if next_page_number < self.num_pages:
            yield scrapy.Request(url = f"www.example.com/page={str(next_page_number)}"

    def parse(self, response) # Parse the main product page
        #....
        try:
            new_url = 'www.exampleAPI.com/' + item['active_col_num']
        except TypeError:
            new_url = 'www.exampleAPI.com/{dummy_number}'
    
        yield scrapy.Request(new_url, callback=self.parse_attr, meta={'item': item}, priority = 2)
```

With this spider configuration - spider will process product pages of next page only when it finish processing products from previous pages and your application will not receive long queue of requests/response.

**2.Http compression**

A lot websites compress html code to reduce traffic load. 
For example Amazon website compress it's product pages using gzip. 
Average size of compressed html of amazon product page ~250Kb 
Size of uncompressed html can exceed ~1.5Mb.

In case if Your website use compression and response sizes of uncompressed html is similar to size of amazon product pages - app will require to spend a lot of memory to hold both compressed and uncompressed response bodies.
And `DownloaderStats` middleware that populates `downloader/response_bytes` stats parameter will not count size of uncompresses responses as it's `process_response` method called before `process_response` method of `HttpCompressionMiddleware` middleware.

In order to check it you will need to change priority of Downloader stats middleware by adding this to settings:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats':50
}
```

In this case:
`downloader/request_bytes` stats parameter - will be reduced as it will not count size of some headers populated by middlewares. 
`downloader/response_bytes` stats parameter - will be greatly increased in case if website uses compression.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about the priority parameter, will test this out tonight. 

To confirm my understanding, could you elaborate on why the crawler is fine, but after say 1hr, it crashes from exceeding the memory? Slightly confused as the oldest request does not get much higher than 100s, from `trackref.print_live_refs()`. Especially as the total size of the 20k items is around 40mb - Think I'm missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Ok. I have some theories. Anyway this behaviour is not expected. I can expect something similar in case if application trying to download a lot of files/images/videos but not regular html.

Comment: After testing the downloader stats middleware, the behaviour you suspected is true. As this is true, what is the solution? Seems changing this still results in a memory leak. - Note I haven' has time to test the new architecture you suggest first, yet

Comment: Can you post `downloader/response_bytes` and `downloader/response_count` stats values of the latest run ( with changed `DownloaderStats` priority)?. For next tests please remove that change of `SETTINGS`.

Comment: Rerun the crawler with a subset of the full website: response_bytes old = 25278903, response_count old = 969, request_bytes old = 351822 ### response_bytes new = 159938140, response_count new = 969, request_bytes new = 173131. Let me know if sending you the full crawler / website would help.. Also added output from scrapinghub stats after adding the middleware.

Comment: It is require in RAM memory to allocate 10-20x of response size to process single response with compression!!!

In case if priority changes of your spider will not reduce memory usage the latest thing I can recommend - is to separate scraping job into several (1st run - 1-40 pages, 2nd - 41-80 pages,etc. not 1-418 pages in single run.)